# Evaluate the integral $\int \frac{x + 2}{x^2 - 4x + 4}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to integrate $\int \frac{x+2}{x^2-4x+4}dx$. Since the integrand is a proper rational function, I may use the method of partial fraction decomposition. The integral can be evaluated as follows:

\begin{equation}
\int \frac{x+2}{x^2-4x+4}dx = \int \frac{(x-2)+4}{(x-2)^2}dx = \int \frac{1}{x-2}dx+ \int \frac{4}{(x-2)^2}dx = ln|x-2|-\frac{4}{x-2}+C
\end{equation}

My question arises in the partial fraction decomposition. I know the denominator can be factored as $(x-2)^2 = (x-2)(x-2)$. Thus, I obtain the following decomposition:

\begin{equation}
\frac{x+2}{x^2-4x+4} = \frac{A}{x-2} + \frac{B}{x-2}
\end{equation}

Multiplying both sides of the equation by $x^2-4x+4$ gives:

\begin{equation}
x+2 = A(x-2)+B(x-2) = (A+B)x+(-2A-2B)
\end{equation}

Thus, I obtain the following system of equations:

\begin{equation}
A+B=1 \text{ and } -2A -2B = 2 \\
A+B=1 \text{ and } A+B=-1
\end{equation}

I arrive at the contradiction that $A+B = 1 = -1$. This occurred because the correct decomposition is:

\begin{equation}
\frac{x+2}{x^2-4x+4} = \frac{A}{x-2} + \frac{B}{(x-2)^2} = \frac{A}{x-2} + \frac{B}{x^2-4x+4}
\end{equation}

This can be rewritten as:

\begin{equation}
\frac{x+(2-B)}{x^2-4x+4} = \frac{A}{x-2} = \frac{A(x-2)}{x^2-4x+4}
\end{equation}

Multiplying both sides of the equation by $x^2-4x+4$ gives:

\begin{equation}
x+(2-B) = A(x-2) = Ax+(-2A)
\end{equation}

I obtain the following system of equations:

\begin{equation}
A=1 \text{ and } -2A = 2-B \\
A=1 \text{ and } -2 = 2-B \\
A=1 \text{ and } B = 4
\end{equation}

Why must I use $\frac{B}{(x-2)^2}$ instead of $\frac{B}{x-2}$ in the decomposition?

Answer (score 1):

Think about it like this: the expression
$$ \frac{A}{x - 2} + \frac{B}{x - 2} = \frac{A + B}{x - 2} $$
can never be equal to
$$ \frac{x + 2}{x^2 - 4 x + 4} $$
except if the denominator of the latter just so happens to reduce to $x - 2$.
This is because the former expression really *is* a constant divided by a linear polynomial, but the latter is a linear polynomial divided by a quadratic.

To remedy this, we need to ensure that the proposed partial fractions decomposition can produce an honest-to-goodness linear numerator, and we do this by taking
$$ \frac{A}{x - 2} + \frac{B}{(x - 2)^2} $$
so that when combine these using common denominator, the $A$ gets a linear factor.

Answer (score 0):

> Why must I use $\frac{B}{(x-2)^2}$ instead of $\frac{B}{x-2}$ in the decomposition?

When you decompose it as
$\displaystyle
\frac{x+2}{(x-2)^2}=\frac{A}{x-2}+\frac{B}{x-2}
$
you are actually saying that
$$
\frac{x+2}{(x-2)^2}=\frac{C}{x-2} 
$$
for some constant $C$, which implies that
$$
x^2-4=C(x^2-4x+4)
$$
which has no solution for $C$.

---

Essentially one has the following [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Powers_in_the_denominator):

> Let $f$ and $g$ be nonzero polynomials over a field $K$. Write $g$ as a product of powers of distinct irreducible polynomials :
> $$
> g=\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{n_i}.
> $$
> There are (unique) polynomials $b$ and $a_{ij}$ with $\deg a_{ij} < \deg p_i$ such that
> $$
> \frac{f}{g}=b+\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}\frac{a_{ij}}{p_i^j}.
> $$
> If $\deg f < \deg g$, then $b = 0$.

---

This theorem tells you that the decomposition
$$
\frac{x+2}{(x-2)^2}=\frac{A}{x-2}+\frac{B}{(x-2)^2}
$$
is *unique*. Since it turns out that $B\ne 0$ in this case, one does not have
$$
\frac{x+2}{(x-2)^2}=\frac{C}{x-2}+\frac{D}{x-2}
$$
for any $C$ and $D$.

Comment: The last remark isn't quite true: the theorem guarantees unique $A$ and $B$ *for that choice of denominators*. It says nothing about what can or cannot work for different denominators. E.g., if the numerator in the original problem were $x - 2$, the second ansatz would work just fine.

Comment: @prets: Hmm... I see what you mean. I edited the remark.